# Unable to update value in Firebase Realtime Database with Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to update values in my database when i call this function in my flutter app.
The Debug console shows no error.

But the value in the database is not updating. I am able to fetch the data from database correctly.

```
//to update the motor value in firebase realtime database
void updateMotorValue(bool val) {
  var url = globalServerLink;
  DatabaseReference databaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.refFromURL(url);
  databaseRef.child("ABC_value").update({"value": val});
  print("value changed");
}
```

[image: database schema]

I have tried doing it as it says in the docs. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/flutter/read-and-write.
unable to get it working yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is only the correct solution i had some issues with my firebase project.

```
void updateMotorValue(bool val) {
  var url = globalServerLink;
  DatabaseReference databaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.refFromURL(url);
  databaseRef.child("ABC_value").update({"value": val});
}
```

Used 2 Firebase Projects, app was connected to different database than which i was trying to update data on. Resolved now.

refromURL(url)-> is only used to get to that location in your database. I thought it could create reference from any realtime db url you enter.